# WPF and Control Templates

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I implemented the following control template in a Shared User Control Library

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="WindowTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Border Name="Frame" Style="{StaticResource WindowBorder}" MouseLeftButtonDown="titleBar_MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="50" />
              <RowDefinition Height="*" />
              <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <controls:AppHeader Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Appheader" HeaderTitle="{Binding Path=AppTitle}" HeaderImageSource="{Binding Path=ImageSource}" ></controls:AppHeader>
            <Border Grid.Row="1"  BorderThickness="0,0,0,2"  BorderBrush="#FFC1C1C1">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Border>
            <controls:AppNavigator Grid.Row="2" x:Name="AppNavigator"></controls:AppNavigator>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="WindowToolStyle" TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="400"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="600"/>
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
    <Setter Property="Topmost" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource WindowTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

I also have code behind file this resource file to implement common  functions (like close, dragging window etc..)

```
public partial class WindowToolStyle : ResourceDictionary
{
    public WindowToolStyle()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void titleBar_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
         var window = (Window)((FrameworkElement)sender).TemplatedParent;
         window.DragMove();
    }

}
```

I then style my windows all with  Style="{StaticResource WindowToolStyle}"

The problem is that I need to access the objects declared in the control template from the window that is being styled with this template, how do i do this? Thanks!

(I followed this article to do the above http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71485/Reusing-Control-Templates-in-Resource-Dictionaries, the motivation is to create a windows template that can used by all our tools so that we do not repeat code)

Comment: GetTemplateChild returns any named object that is created in your style (like your "AppHeader").

Comment: That does not work, since my template is defined in a User Control library, any further ideas?

Answer (score -1):

http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-part-names

use teplatesPart attribute in your window then in OnApplyTeplate() get referenc to your parts in template

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.